# Automatically add posts and categories to Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

my menu displays categories and posts related to them which appear by a drop down when we click on the category item. 
My question is : is it possible to add the categories and the posts that belong to those categories automatically, without going on "appearance" - "menu" to manually add each category and posts?
Thanks.